# Logistic regression with only one variable?

Tags: regression, logistic

I mistyped in stata "logistic a" where a is a binary variable and to my surprise it actually ran.

What is a logistic regression doing when it's running without any independent variables?

[image]

Comment: It might be just fitting the null model (intercept only, log-odds of being in the class of interest). To verify, please edit your question to show the class breakdown of your binary variable a and the output from the command you ran.

Comment: Edited my answer, does this suffice?

Comment: Incidentally, you can do this with regress, ologit, etc. In all cases you get an intercept only model: a heavy-handed way to characterize the mean/proportion, etc. of the dependent variable. Contrast `mean a` with `regress a` with Odds/(Odds+1) from your output above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an intercept-only model. Stata's notation `_cons` is the intercept term. With no other regressors, the odds is $p/(1-p)$ where $p$ is the proportion with positive response.

Comment: I understand what the intercept and the constant is, but I'm still not sure if this actually tells me anything about my variable?

Comment: @Paze I have already shown you how the value of "Odds" relates to the frequency of your variable `ShuntEffekt`.